# Proguard not obfuscating methods and classes names

Tags: java, android

i have used default config, no changes were made...

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

i don't know if it needs an specific config

Sorry for my bad english

More info:

i have tested with dex2jar and java decompiler and i can see the name of the classes and methods

Comment: What are you trying to do? An application or custom rom?

Comment: @blganesh101 An application

Comment: Did you "Export signed application package"? proguard doesn't get applied in debug apks

Comment: @weston i have exported the app and follow the assistant, don't know if it's the problem

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I think things have changed since I last did this. I'll let someone else answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK only applies ProGuard when you create a release build, with ant release or by exporting the apk in Eclipse.